# format datestring based on locale without creating Date object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, date, format, locale

I have a date string which looks like this: 2013-04-06T14:15:00
I'm looking for functions similar to toLocaleDateString()
[(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). However, those functions don't take a String parameter; you need to create a Date object first. I'm trying to avoid timezones altogether, so does anyone know of a function (standard or from a plugin) which can format a datestring using a specific locale's rules (1/17/2013 vs 17/1/2013 etc.) using only my datestring?

I'm currently using jQuery, and this plugin for formatting dates: [jQuery.dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

Comment: Would be better to format it correctly at the source. Any reason why this can't be done? Where are you getting the string data from?

Comment: this date string is returned from a server

Comment: Whats wrong with `new Date("1/17/2013")`?

Comment: or new Date("2013-04-06T14:15:00")

Comment: @RoddyPiper: Do you control the server code, because it would be better to return the string in the local format. You can get the browsers local preferences from the Request data, and use that to determine the format

Comment: the date object becomes "Sat Apr 06 2013 10:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"; a timezone was applied to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your date string to the Date constructor. It parses most legitimate formats.

```
new Date("1/17/2013")
new Date("2013-04-06T14:15:00")
```

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to paste the output and look at it further, I realize its going to be sufficient as long as I convert the date object back to GMT